# Java Industry Standard: Arrays/ArrayLists/Linked Lists

Tags: java

My professor told us that Linked Lists are used as an industry standard with Java based programming over Arrays/Array Lists. Is that true, are there any professionals that use one or the other or a mix of them, or is there something else you use?

Comment: They solve different tasks, why would one replace the other?

Comment: I personally prefer `ArrayList` as it provides better random access performance over `LinkedList`, but is limited by the constraints of the backing array. So, it's a matter of the right tool for the right job

Comment: `ArrayList` is definitely the default.

Comment: Your professor lives in an alternate reality.

Comment: `LinkedList` is terrible for cache locality. I remember [DrDeprecator](https://twitter.com/drdeprecator/status/668447303481495552) saying that it might be deprecated, but other things to deprecate first.

Comment: I have never seen anyone using `LinkedList` and never seen professors actually working on code used by industry.